# What does $w_{\tau}=-w_x$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, terminology

Problem and solution given at http://exir.ru/1/resh/1_106.htm

> A small washer put on the inclined plane, which makes an angle α with the horizon, and reported the initial velocity $v_0$ (Fig. 1.27). Find the dependence of the speed of the puck angle $\phi$, if the coefficient of friction $k = \tan \alpha$ and the initial moment $\phi_0 = \pi / 2$.

Solution is also given on the same site but is in Russian. And I couldn't figure it out myself.

Basically there are three forces, friction, normal and gravity. If we consider only the plane of the incline, we have gravity+ normal =$mg \sin \alpha$, and friction =$mg \sin \alpha$.

Firstly, will the direction of frictional force always be opposite to the direction of motion at each instant, irrespective of the fact that there is gravity? And if so, how do we solve it? Does $W$ mean work done? Work done by gravity (+normal) will be $mg \Delta x$, and work done by friction will be $mg \Delta l$, where $\Delta x$ is downward distance fallen, and $\Delta l$ is total path length. There seems to be no relation between the two. So how do we do it?

Comment: This post (v4) seems more about translating from Russian than physics. The subscript $\tau$ likely stands for friction (=трение).

Comment: @Qmechanic It's not just that. Only someone who understands the solution can actually translate it. And if they understand the solution, they are as good as providing it themselves. Basically I'm asking for any simple valid solution....doesn't have to exactly match the given solution actually....

Comment: What does "cp 0" mean?

Comment: @Qmechanic The site says my question was closed because "Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem." Well, firstly I had put considerable effort into figuring out the answer myself. Also I am asking about a specific physics concept only.

Comment: @Qmechanic (message contd.) The first doubt was as to whether friction will always oppose the direction of motion in this instance (meaning there is only kinetic and no static friction). The second doubt was on how exactly to solve the problem (with or without calculus). The required solution was a bit counter-intuitive (atleast for me), so what was wrong in hoping the someone on this community could solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine sent the solution.....

[image]

[image]